# My for loops does not re run input for in.nextLine?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I am trying to create a program which takes in a name and an age and stores them in their respected arrays. When the program is run, it ignores the line:

`personName[i] = in.nextLine();`

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Persons {
  public static void main (String[] args){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] personName = new String[9];
    int[] personAge = new int[9];

    for(int i = 0; i < personName.length; i++){
      System.out.println("Please enter a name: ");
      personName[i] = in.nextLine();
      if(!personName[i].equalsIgnoreCase("done")){
        System.out.println("Please enter an age: ");
        personAge[i] = in.nextInt();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please add your language tag next time or ([edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40487474/edit))

Comment: What are you inputting as a name?

Comment: @Thomas the answer below does answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

You have tried to read the integer value without reading entire line.

Change your line to:

```
    personAge[i] = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
```

Comment: Importing anything from `java.lang` is unnecessary, unless the package defines its own `Integer` class.

Comment: @RolandIllig yes, you are right. It's not neccessery. But this is not an error. Anyway I edit the answer.